# Is is possible to write own telegram library using MTPROTO API using Python?

Tags: python, telegram, mtproto

I have searched many things in the google and cannot find document. I found MTPROTO API document from telegram official web site but they dont provide any guide to use in python and only explain those APIs. I know telethon can be used.

Is is possible to write own telegram library using MTPROTO API using Python? rather than using 3rd party library.

Comment: there is no difference between 3rd party library you say and your own. if you do this it will be 3rd party same as others.